# React-Native: FlatList onRefresh not called on pull up.

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

**Current Behavior:**

I'm trying to update a list gotten from a server by pulling up on the view. When I do the onRefresh does not fire.

I've set the GET request in the callback of the setState function, but that didn't seem to do anything.

**Expected Behavior:**

Pulling up on the view calls onRefresh function.

Code:

```
...
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stories: [],
      isFetching: false,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() { this.fetchData() }
  onRefresh() {
    this.setState({ isFetching: true }, function() { this.fetchData() });
  }
  fetchData() {
    var that = this;
    axios.get('http://192.168.0.13:3000/api/story/get/by/geo')
      .then((res) => {
        that.setState({ stories: res.data, isFetching: false });
        that.props.dispatch(StoryActions.setStories(res.data))
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <FlatList
          onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()}
          refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
          data={this.state.stories}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
          renderItem={({item}) => (<StoryFeed story={item} id={item.id} /> )}
          />
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
```

**Version Information**

React-Native: 0.45.0

Node: 7.4.0

Comment: I would think `onRefresh` is the wrong place to put it.  Why not just stick it in `render()`?  Maybe I misunderstand, but using a refresh function like that seems to me to kind of defeat the whole purpose of the functional code ...

Comment: According to the docs (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) onRefresh is a property of FlatList. Not sure how you would be it in render.

Comment: that's fine, but I don't think `onRefresh` will get called when you think it will get called.  In functional programming, such as JS6 w/ React+Redux, you don't change state, you make a new state. Your state tree didn't change, so a new state wasn't made.

Comment: Try just console logging something in refresh and I think you will see it's never getting hit in your current code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Issue with React-Native. FlatList does not seem to detect onRefresh when nested inside ScrollView: Issue ticket: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14756

Answer (score 50):

Commenting since this ranked high on <strike>google</strike> bing for my search.

In my case there was an automatic import of another FlatList that didn't behave exactly as I wanted (it didn't seem to have an "onRefresh"):

```
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

What I really wanted:

```
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
```

Now for investigating why we have this dependency. ;)

Comment: Worth noting `import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';` will work on `iOS` but not on `Android`

Answer (score 12):

I have faced this issue. sometimes `IDE` picks wrong `Flatlist` component in auto complete code. `IDE` consider `react-native-gesture-handler` of Flatlist. `react-native-gesture-handler` of `Flatlist` is not supported `onRefresh`. `react-native` of `Flatlist` only support the `onRefresh`.

So Need to change `react-native` of `Flatlist` component.

Instead of

```
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Try this

```
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into the same issue. Resolved it by **adding refreshControl prop to the parent component of Flatlist which would be Content or Scrollview** like this:

```
import { StyleSheet, RefreshControl } from 'react-native';

 refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
            onRefresh={() => this.handleRefresh()}
          />
        }
```

...

Comment: on componentdidmount i setIsRefreshing = true but refreshCOntrol not show

Answer (score 0):

You might be using RefreshControl as a props in ScrollView:
[Example and Guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol)

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that flatlist is not nested inside scrollview,
[discussed here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14756)

Answer (score -2):

I also had this issue for some time. I found the solution on [this](https://snack.expo.io/HJc-0uygW) expo example.

This is a snippet of that example:

```
return (
      <ScrollView>
        <FlatList
          onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()}
          refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
          data={this.state.stories}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
          renderItem={({item}) => (<StoryFeed story={item} id={item.id} /> )}
          />
      </ScrollView>
    )
```